How to upgrade only packages with Priority: required or Essential: yes on Debian systems?
Priority and Essential information as shown in apt show section.

With apt 1.9.9 and later (available since Debian 11):
sudo apt install --only-upgrade ~prequired ~E

will upgrade required and essential packages (and any necessary dependencies, based on version constraints).
If your version of apt doesn’t support the above, you can use aptitude instead:
sudo aptitude upgrade ~prequired ~E

Note that in a stable release, required and essential packages don’t get special treatment, so at least from a Debian perspective there isn’t a particular reason to limit upgrades to those packages only — you should keep your systems up-to-date generally. If you only upgrade required and essential packages you will miss upgrades to transitively-essential packages. This is actually dangerous — if the xz backdoor had made it to a release, fixing that would have involved upgrading liblzma, which is neither required nor essential.

Any way to upgrade base system packages only?
